# GLTFLoader is not defined - THREE.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm trying to build a website with a scrollable animation using three.js and anime.js. Everything up until now is in working condition (this means i have a cube in a space that i can see through a camera, when i scroll - the cube and the camera move through various keyframes until at the end of their timeline. My next task was to bring in a blender object to replace the cube. The THREEjs docs advise me to use GLTFLoader, when trying to implement this:

I received the error:

**GLTFLoader is not defined.**

Here is the code it references:

```
var loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load(
        '/assets/logotext.glb',
        function ( gltf ) {
            // called when the resource is loaded
            scene.add( gltf.scene );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            // called while loading is progressing
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% + loaded' );
        },
        function ( error ) {
            // called when loading has errors
            console.error( 'An error happened', error );
        },
    );
```

Here is how I include the scripts in my html:

```
<script src="\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.min.js"></script>
       <script src="\node_modules\three\build\three.js"></script>
      <script src="\node_modules\three\examples\js\loaders\GLTFLoader.js"></script>
     <script src="index.js"></script>      
  </body>
</html>
```

The full files can be found here if I haven't included enough: [index.html](https://controlc.com/5f1aa628), [index.js](https://controlc.com/1cb9cf78)

If there is any other part of this you need to see just say and I can edit the question.

Thankyou!

Comment: Try to create `GLTFLoader` with the `THREE` namespace. So `var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();`.

Comment: Thanks! If i don't end every exchange on stackoverflow feeling like a dummy then i'm not learning (: All works as expected now.

Comment: I spent so much time trying to change the src and import methods to get gltfloader working! thank you so much for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

You should instantiate the GLTFLoader constructor using its parent class constructor that is the 'THREE' constructor, like I have shown above. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor
    at scene1.js:5:16........  This error pops up when using 'THREE.GLTFLoader'